# DTD - Is there a way to require an attribute with a specific value be present?

Tags: xml, dtd

I want to do require something like this:

```
<div type="foobar"></div>
```

In layman speak I want to require the document to have a foobar type element. More specifically I want to require the attribute value pair type **and** "foobar" to be uniquely present.

I realize I can do something like:

```
<!ATTLIST div type CDATA #REQUIRED>
```

But this doesn't constrain the value like I want.

Alternatively

```
<!ATTLIST div type CDATA #FIXED "foobar">
```

Requires the attribute to be a certain value. This is close to what I want, but I want other values to be possible. I just want to make sure there is **one** definition of the attribute/value pair present.
Is there a way to do this with a XML DTD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an enumeration:

```
<!ATTLIST div
          type (foobar) #REQUIRED>
```

Other values are possible by adding them to the enumeration.

For example, the following declaration requires a `type` attribute on the `div` element with either the value `foobar` or `barfoo`.

```
<!ATTLIST div
          type (foobar|barfoo) #REQUIRED>
```

See "Enumerated Attribute Types" in http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-attribute-types for more info.